# What kind of view am I looking for?

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiview, uitextfield

I am creating a `tableView` on my **iPad** app where one of the `cells` has a `UIButton` titled "Edit notes". I would like a view to pop up over the screen containing a "textfield" and the keyboard, not a new view/push. Prefferably not even covering the whole screen. I guess I am looking for the view used when you have your iPad in landscape mode and you compose a new e-mail. A view popping up from beneath while you can still see the main view in the background.

I've been looking around, but I have no clue what to search for!

Here's an image of something like what I'm talking about, only I would need it to say "Save" instead of "Send" and without the "to/Cc/subject"-fields, and I guess I would require an NSString as return value. Any clues?

Or something similar!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called modal presentation style.

You can present any `UIViewController` or its subclasses.

Set the `modalPresentationStyle`property to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`and present this viewController from an parent viewController (your tableViewController perhaps) with the `presentViewController:animated:completition:`  method.

Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW75).

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, search for an object called "Container View". You can include whatever you want in this container and show/hide it when you need.